# How to find the average of returned result?

Tags: mysql

I'm a beginner in MySQL.I have a table with columns named "ID", "Name", "CountryCode" and "Population". I have select the top 5 rows with following code:

```
SELECT ID, Name, CountryCode, Population FROM city 
LIMIT 5;
```

Now I want to find the average population of the 5 returned result, how do I do it? I tried the code below, didn't work. Please help

```
SELECT AVG(Population)
    FROM (
        SELECT ID, Name, CountryCode, Population
    FROM city LIMIT 5);
```

Comment: You need an order by population desc to get the top 5.

Comment: What does “didn’t work” mean? Errors? Wrong results?

Comment: when executing my code, I got error code:1248. Every derived table must have its own alias. Not sure what it means

Answer (score 0):

You might get errors like this "Every derived table must have its own alias"

A derived table means a query in brackets, so you should alias it like `AS whatever`. This would help.

```
SELECT AVG(Population)
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Name, CountryCode, Population
FROM city ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5) AS DOC5;
```

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I will reflect your suggestion in the post.